# AWS S3 and AjaXplorer

Tags: amazon-s3, file-management, pydio

I'm using AjaXplorer to give access to my clients to a shared directory stored in Amazon S3. I installed the SD, configured the plugin (http://ajaxplorer.info/plugins/access/s3/) and could upload and download files but the upload size is limited to my host PHP limit which is 64MB.

Is there a way I can upload directly to S3 without going over my host to improve speed and have S3 limit, no PHP's?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible, because the server will first climb to the PHP file and then make transfer to bucket.

Maybe

Answer (score 0):

The only way around this is to use some JQuery or JS that can bypass your server/PHP entirely and stream directly into S3. This involves enabling CORS and creating a signed policy on the fly to allow your uploads, but it can be done!

I ran into just this issue with some inordinately large media files for our website users that I no longer wanted to host on the web servers themselves.

The best place to start, IMHO is here:
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

A demo is here:
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

This was written to upload+write files to a variety of locations, including S3. The only tricky bits are getting your MIME type correct for each particular upload, and getting your bucket policy the way you need it.